# Python Gurobi, report of statistics presolve

Tags: python, attributes, gurobi

I try to get number of rows, columns and nonzeros values after presolve. I know about getAttr(GRB.Attr.NumVars), getAttr(GRB.Attr.NumConstrs)...but they give the statics before presolve. Can any one help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If m is the model, i create new model for presolve (mpre = m.presolve()), and then i use mpre.getAttr(GRB.Attr.NumVars), mpre.getAttr(GRB.Attr.NumConstrs) and mpre.getAttr(GRB.Attr.NumConstrs), mpre.getAttr(GRB.Attr.NumNZs).